# ElasticSearch - Phrase match on whole document? Not just one specific field

Tags: elasticsearch, match, quote, phrase, match-phrase

Is there a way I can use elastic match_phrase on an entire document? Not just one specific field.

We want the user to be able to enter a search term with quotes, and do a phrase match anywhere in the document.

```
{
    "size": 20,
    "from": 0,
    "query": {
        "match_phrase": {
            "my_column_name": "I want to search for this exact phrase"
        }
    }
}
```

Currently, I have only found phrase matching for specific fields. I must specify the fields to do the phrase matching within.

Our document has hundreds of fields, so I don't think its feasible to manually enter the 600+ fields into every match_phrase query. The resultant JSON would be huge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [multi-match query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html) with type phrase that runs a match_phrase query on each field and uses the _score from the best field. See phrase and phrase_prefix.

> If no fields are provided, the multi_match query defaults to the
> index.query.default_field index settings, which in turn defaults to *.
> This extracts all fields in the mapping that are eligible to term queries and filters the metadata fields. All extracted fields are then
> combined to build a query.

Adding a working example with index data, search query and search result

**Index data:**

```
{
    "name":"John",
    "cost":55,
    "title":"Will Smith"
}
{
    "name":"Will Smith",
    "cost":55,
    "title":"book"
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "Will Smith",
      "type": "phrase"
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "64519840",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1.2199391,
        "_source": {
          "name": "Will Smith",
          "cost": 55,
          "title": "book"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "64519840",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 1.2199391,
        "_source": {
          "name": "John",
          "cost": 55,
          "title": "Will Smith"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: @AllenH. glad this worked for you and thank u for accepting my answer 

Answer (score 0):

You can use * in match query field parameter which will search all the available field in the document. But it will reduce your query speed since you are searching the whole document

Comment: Hi, I tried this but it isnt working. Am I doing it right?
{
    "size": 20,
    "from": 0,
    "query": {
        "match_phrase": {
            "*": "my phrase 123"
        }
    }
}